# Return class object based on condition

Tags: c#, abstract-class

How to Return a class object on different condition.

Suppose if my result is success return Authentication, else return Class Error.

```
public Class Example
{
  public Authentication GetDetails(int id)
  {
         Authentication objAuth = new Authentication();

         if(id==100)
         {
             return objAuth ;
         }  
         else
         {
              ClassB objB=new ClassB ();
              return  objB;
         }
    }
}

static Void Main()
{
    Example obj = new Example();
    obj.GetDetails();
}
```

Comment: You should use exceptions.

Comment: You're reinventing a square wheel. Please consider throwing an exception if authentication fails.

Comment: As for exceptions in common scenarios https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#handle-common-conditions-without-throwing-exceptions

Comment: Your method is named "isValid" which implies it's a boolean. What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Updated Method name

Comment: No you can't. If return type of method is A then you can't return B from it unless B is inherited from A. Your use case is not proper. If you are ending up this kind if requirement then you need to re-look at your design.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain You are not even using the return value. Does it matter what you return? Your method could as well be `public void GetDetails() { /* whatever */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to be a return type which both objects inherit from. If they don't have a common base class, then it will have to have a return type of Object. I would add though, that if they don't inherit from a common parent, then you probably should code this in a different way. You don't want to have calls to the function need to figure out what type of object they are getting back.  If you give more details on what you are trying to do then people can help steer you in a better direction. The above comments suggesting throwing an exception are likely the direction you should go in.

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. Sorry to confuse writing ErrorMessage class. Lets assume i want to return Class B object if my condition was not satisfied.